# Adobe Animate/Flash ios Application Uploader

Tags: ios, flash, air, adobe, application-loader

Anyone been able to get a project from Adobe Animate CC into TestFlight?  Every time I build in Animate and then upload with the Application Loader I get the following error:

`ERROR-ITMS-90017: "This bundle is invalid. The IPA format requires a top-level directory named Playload, containing ona a .app bundle and optional plugins in a Plugins directory".`

The app is very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Ensure you have added the following entitlements to your app descriptor xml...

```
<Entitlements><![CDATA[
<key>get-task-allow</key><false/>
<key>beta-reports-active</key><true/>
]]></Entitlements>
```

And make sure you publish your app for App Store.

Comment: Yep that was it.  Also for some reason I had multiple lines in the <filename> and <name> tags as well.  Reduced those to 1 each

Comment: When you get around to publishing your app to the App Store remember to remove the <key>beta-reports-active</key><true/>.